Is this ODE solvable with the given information?
I have the 2nd order differential equation: $$\frac{d^2 z}{d \rho^2} = \frac{z}{\rho} - \frac{3}{2} \frac{z^2}{\rho^2} + \frac{\alpha}{2} \frac{z^3}{\rho ^3}$$
With the boundary condition that $\frac{dz}{d \rho} |_{\rho = 0} = 0$ and that in the limit as $\rho$ goes to $\infty$, z tends to some value $z_0$. I want to use the Runge-Kutta method to approximate this, but I'm uncertain what my initial point would be. Setting $y = z'$, I have the system of equations: $$y = \frac{dz}{d \rho}, \space \space\space\space\space y' = \frac{z}{\rho} - \frac{3}{2} \frac{z^2}{\rho^2} + \frac{\alpha}{2} \frac{z^3}{\rho ^3}$$ I know $y(0) = 0$, so this should be the initial point, but as I don't know what $z(\rho)$ is I don't know what the z value of the initial point should be. Do I not have enough information to solve this? Can I incorporate the limit $z_0$ somehow?

You must also have $z(0)=0$ for the ODE to have a chance of being well-defined. You will still need to handle $\rho=0$ carefully
